# Пытаюсь подключить react-leaflet, но при запуске получаю ошибку SyntaxError:Support for the experimental syntax 'flow' isn't currently enabled (10:8)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babel, leafletjs

К новому react проекту установил react-leaflet, нужны карты. при запуске npm start, выдаёт ошибку:
`"SyntaxError: D:\Development\JS\SnapServiceClient\snap_service_client\node_modules\react-leaflet\src\index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'flow' isn't currently enabled (10:8)"`.

Как я понимаю, какая-то JS фича не работает, для чего нужен плагин для babel.

Компилятор подсказывает: `Add @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types (https://git.io/vb49g) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.`

Ну вот, пытался в react-leaflet в файл .babelrc в plugins добавить строчку в массив "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types", но это не помогло делу.

В какой конфиг нужно это вставить, подскажите, пожалуйста.
[image: скриншот ошибки]

Comment: Похоже, проблема связана с тем, что create-react-app не даёт читать .babelrc, хотя я не особо понимаю как эти конфиги все работают. Как заставить его читать конфиги?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы не используйте Flow в своем проекте, импортируйте таким образом

```
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet/es'
```